# How to Read the Control of a Debian Packages in c++?

Tags: c++, debian, package

I am trying to read the data from the control file of a Debian Package, like the next example, in C++:

```
Package: com.example.test
Version: 1.0
...
Homepage: http://example.com
...
```

I can read it with the following code, but when it is in the Homepage I only get "http":

```
string item;

vector<string> data;

stringstream str(line);

while(getline(str, item, ':' )) {
    data.push_back(item);
}
```

How can I read "Homepage" into `data[0]` and get data with `data[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only specify `:` as ending the field when you read the *first* item on a line.

```
std::string key, value;

while (std::getline(infile, key, ':'))
     std::getline(infile, value);
```

Instead of a vector of strings alternating between keys and values, I'd probably use an `std::map` (or possibly `std::multimap`), which is built fairly specifically for situations like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> package_data;

while (std::getline(infile, key, ':')) {
     std::getline(infile, value);

     package_data[key] = value;
}
```

Then, you can look up values directly from keys:

```
 std::string homepage = *package_data.find("Homepage");
```